# Output generated link using onchange

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, innerhtml, onsubmit

I have the following code.

**JS :**

```
function generateLink()
{
  var car = document.getElementById('cars').value;
  var year = document.getElementById('years').value;

  if(car  == "fiat" || car == "honda" || car == "mitsu" || car == "acura" || car == "ford")
        document.ref.action ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net';
  else if(car == "audi" || car == "volvo" || car == "mazda" || car == "nissan" || car == "porsche" || car == "wholesale")
        document.ref.action ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net/Sales.jsp';
  else if(car == "BMW")
        document.ref.action ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net/container.jsp';
  else
        document.ref.action ='/error-pages/404.html';
  return true;
}

function showLink()
{
document.getElementById("years").innerHTML = "Link: " + generateLink();
}
```

**HTML :

```
<h1>Ref</h1>
<form name="ref" onsubmit="return generateLink();" target="_blank">

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:500px;">

  <div style="float:left;"><span>PICK A CAR</span><br>
    <select id="cars">
     …
    </select>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;"><span>PICK A YEAR</span><br>
    <select id="years" onchange="showLink()">
    …
    </select>
  </div>

  <div style="float:left; margin-left:190px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top:70px;">
    <a href=generateLink() id="link"></a>
    <input type="submit" value="Go to Site"><br><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Selection">
  </div>

 ...
```

What I want to do is to output the generated link above the `submit` button after the user changes the `years` field. Ideally, I would like it to be generated only if the first field `cars` was changed as well, but I am not sure how how to do it yet and it is crucial for now.
I know I should be using `onchange`, but I am not sure how to make it actually output the link from the `generateLink` function.

**Edit:**

I was able to output it using the following function and adding the id `link` above the submit button. The link shows up but I am not sure how to make the `href` address accurate based on the selections.

```
function showLink()
{
  var car = document.getElementById('cars').value;
  var year = document.getElementById('years').value;

  if(car  == "fiat" || car == "honda" || car == "mitsu" || car == "acura" || car == "ford")
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net';
  else if(car == "audi" || car == "volvo" || car == "mazda" || car == "nissan" || car == "porsche" || car == "wholesale")
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net/Sales.jsp';
  else if(car == "BMW")
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net/container.jsp';
  else
        document.getElementById("link").innerHTML ='/error-pages/404.html';
}
```

Comment: How you know if the first field cars was changed as well?

Comment: Did you want to generate link for if we only change cars from dropdown?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna The submit button generates a link based on the selection of the two dropdowns whenever it is being clicked on and it works fine. I am not sure how I would output the link that is being generated though. I would like the link to show up after the year is changed (the second dropdown). Again, ideally the link would show up after the year was changed ONLY if the car was changed as well, but I am not too worried about it now.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I do not know. That's why I said ideally it would be the case that the link is shown only if both fields are changed, but it is not something I am planning on doing right now.

Comment: Ok @Nik what is the default option in the cars list?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki acura

Comment: So why you want the list car change, if the user want really the acura that is by default selected and he just changing the year why that should not work?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki You are right. I added the `onchange` to `cars` as well so it would output the link when the default year is the desired one. Not sure what I thinking before.. Still not sure how to have the link direct to the correct `url` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just apppend the generated link to the `#link` element below :

```
function showLink()
{
  var link = generateLink();

  document.getElementById("link").href = link;
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = link;
}
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function generateLink()
{
  var car = document.getElementById('cars').value;
  var year = document.getElementById('years').value;

  if(car  == "fiat" || car == "honda" || car == "mitsu" || car == "acura" || car == "ford")
    link ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net';
  else if(car == "audi" || car == "volvo" || car == "mazda" || car == "nissan" || car == "porsche" || car == "wholesale")
    link ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net/Sales.jsp';
  else if(car == "BMW")
    link ='http://' + year + '.' + car + '.domain.net/container.jsp';
  else
    link ='/error-pages/404.html';

  return link;
}

function showLink()
{
  var link = generateLink();
  
  document.getElementById("link").href = link;
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = link;
}

document.ref.onsubmit = function(){
    this.action = generateLink();
}
```

```html
<h1>Ref</h1>
<form name="ref" target="_blank">

  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:500px;">

    <div style="float:left;"><span>PICK A CAR</span><br>
      <select id="cars" onchange="showLink()">
        <option value="acura">Acura</option>
        <option value="wholesale">Wholesale</option>
        <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div style="float:right;"><span>PICK A YEAR</span><br>
      <select id="years" onchange="showLink()">
        <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2013">2013</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div style="float:left; margin-left:190px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top:70px;">
      <a href="generateLink()" id="link"></a><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Go to Site"><br><br>
      <input type="reset" value="Reset Selection">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Check please if that what you're looking for?

Comment: It fixed the link part (works great), but now the `submit` button doesn't redirect to the url. It just opens the same page in a new tab. I assume it is because now `generateLink` returns a String and doesn't make the action anymore?

Comment: Yes that right.. why you need the `generateLink()` function in the on submit?

Comment: I was planning on customizing the button next. I just think it would look better to have the `url` appear in addition to the original submit button.

Comment: I think you've to set the action attribute instead in the submit event. check my update. (https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/250/)

Comment: That's odd. When I use your edits into my code, copy paste your full code into mine, or when I "Run Code Snippet" - it doesn't work. When I go to the `jsfiddle` link you added - it does seem to be working.

Comment: Yes since the snippet here block the submit requests.

Comment: That would mean that just copying your code into mine should work, but it does not. It still opens the same page when I click `submit`. I am really not sure why.

Comment: I have not, no. I am trying, but it still doesn't open the `url` using the `submit` button.